# Replace pwd with USER in a file

Tags: search, vim, replace, macvim

I know that this is quite an easy thing for any advanced Vim programmer, but I have been trying to find a solution for a couple of hours now.

In my results file, there are certain lines like:

```
/Users/name/Project/Task1/folder1 : INFO : Random Info message
```

Here, `/Users/name/Project/Task1/folder1` is my `pwd` i.e present working directory.

I want to replace all the occurrences of my pwd above in the file with '*USER*'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can simply use the [search and replace functionality](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) and escape the `/` character like this:

```
:%s/\/Users\/name\/Project\/Task1\/folder1/USER/
```

If you need to replace multiple current working directories (and thus want to have the `pwd` to be dynamic) it is probably easier to use something like `sed`:

```
sed "s~$(pwd)~USER~" < file
```

Note that the `~` is used as a delimiter for the command instead of the `/`, this way we do not need to escape the `/` in the path.

Comment: Thanks. I know the basic search and replace. I needed to confirm if there was a way to use $pwd output in the search and replace command.

Comment: I tried the `see` command that you mentioned but it doesn't work because there are spaces in names of directories to my `pwd`. It gives the following error: `sed: 1: "s~/Users/name/Box": unterminated substitute pattern`

Comment: My bad, the `sed` pattern should be in `"`, I added them to the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s@/Users/name/Project/Task1/folder1@USER@g
```

or

```
:%s@<C-r>=getcwd()<CR>@USER@g
```

Comment: I don't want to try the first command because it's manual and will take time to fix because I have long paths and have spaces in path.

Comment: I tried the second command but got the following error: `E486: Pattern not found: <C-r>=getcwd()<CR>`

Comment: Type Ctrl + R then =getcwd() then Enter.